# Suggested edits under a certain amount of characters

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I can see the logic behind only allowing edits when a certain number of characters are changed, but sometimes it seems there's a perfectly valid reason for editing a post and just changing a couple of characters (for example putting backticks around a couple of portions of code to make it more readable or correcting a spelling mistake.)

Is this restriction lifted when reputation climbs higher, or does it stay? And if it stays permanently, perhaps it should be lifted at some point? Minor edits can be just as useful as major ones.

Comment: Spelling error corrections also usually consist of only a few changed characters.

Comment: Exactly, that was one of the use cases I pointed out :-) I just think that if people aren't allowed to make small changes like this they're more likely not to edit at all (there's more than one occasion when I've gone to correct a spelling mistake but then haven't because of this restriction.)

Comment: I'm particularly concerned when the minor edit is to a code sample - adding an extra parenthesis or an extra = can make a non-functioning sample much more useful. Sometimes these code errors are very subtle. Shouldn't low rep users be able to submit one or two character edits if they are to code?

Comment: Here's a concrete example of where I cannot suggest an edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440497/very-simple-c-for-statement-but-it-wont-cout The question is actually about the incorrect loop condition, but the missing quote mark confused me when I first read it. I tried to add it in, but I'm not allowed to as it's only a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about suggested edits? Unlike edits by users with 2k rep, suggested edits must be approved and there is a limited [peer review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284), so I'm guessing the reason is so that there aren't lots of minor edits blocking more important ones from being approved.

2k users don't have that restriction (see my test edit to your question) and don't see a warning about it, as you can see by editing a community wiki post (providing you have 100 rep).

Comment: Yup, I am talking about suggested edits - do actual edits not have this restriction then? (Not yet having 2k rep, I wouldn't know!)

Comment: @berry120: No (see my test edit to your question).

Comment: I'd say minor edits are *easier* to review.

Answer (score 3):

Some ways around this, just in case we need some examples:

One user temporarily added junk characters to get to the limit, for an important fix. That took that person 2 edits, to remove the same junk as well:

- https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1782 (added two characters and junk)

  > Clarified that it's Open MPI and not OpenMP; added junk to bottom to work around edit size limit (since the 2-character change is important to meaning)
- https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1783 (deletion of junk)
- https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1784 (same edit, after OP rolled back the good edits)

Someone a bit more creative by changing "Worth a look" into "Certainly worth a look":

- https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1777

And others simply add whitespace to the bottom:

- https://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/76
- https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1821 (excessive whitespace not needed here?)

Comment: Oh, the question of the first example [has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888097/building-boost-with-openmpi-not-working), and hence the edit-suggestions links are now 10k too, I guess. Not sure if that was caused by the editing (which *was* correct), or maybe even my comment about that.

Comment: You forgot `<!-- adding html comments -->` :)

Comment: If you see it happen, you're welcome to add it, @Benjol!

Comment: eh, do I have to admit where I saw it? :P

Comment: Admit *where*, @Benjol, or [the contents](http://atheism.stackexchange.com/edit-suggestions/7) of the comment? ;-)